# Why is std::stringstream not printing the correct numbers in this code?

Tags: c++, vector, txt

So, very new to this. I am trying to change the input from the text file from string to double after I've grabbed it and put it into a vector. I want to perform mathematical operations with those numbers and some of the numbers are missing a digit or two after I've converted from string to double. (the file is converted from doc to txt because I cant figure out how to access doc files, if this is wrong please let me know). I would include the txt file in this question but I cant figure out how. so if that is necessary, please let me know how.
Feel free to criticize the code, always willing to learn. I need it. :)

The numbers are in this exact format -> 0.00000
And some of them are coming out, after conversion, as 0.0000 or  0.000

```
int main() 
{
    std::string lines;
    std::vector <std::string> numbers{};
    std::vector <double> dbnumbers{};
    std::ifstream myfile("data.txt");

    while (myfile >> lines)
    {
        numbers.push_back(lines);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::string tempstring;
        tempstring = numbers[i];
        std::stringstream tempd(tempstring);

        double line{};
        tempd >> line;
        dbnumbers.push_back(line);

    }
    for (auto element : numbers) std::cout << element << " / ";
    for (auto element2 : dbnumbers) std::cout << element2 << " / ";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your code by directly converting from string to double using `double line = atof(tempstring.c_str());` for which you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`. And if you want to print out your doubles with a precision of 5, you can use `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << your_double_var;` for which you need to `#include <iomanip.h>`. Give it a go.

Comment: Please write a small input file and edit your question clarifying what output is expected and why.

Comment: Your problem could be one of several issues. First, you're dumping strings and `double` values. The latter has specific formatting characteristics (width and precision) when sent as formatted output to a stream. Unless you change those characteristics, they have some pretty basic default. Second your choice of example (0.00000) couldn't possibly be worse, because from it we can't say whether it is an accuracy issue when converting to `double` (which aren't always precise), or a formatting issue (which I already discussed). 0 is always zero, but if your *real* data is something else...

Comment: -Costantino : the input file looks like - > 1.58231 etc.. on each new line . the output I want is just exactly those numbers and some of them are coming out as ex. 1.582 or 1.5823 once converted from strings to doubles. But rturrado's answer fixed it :).

Comment: -WhozCraig :  I see what you are saying and that is valuable info. These are the sort of things that I still need to get good at remembering.  I only started learning code about 3 months ago on a cheap mobile and got a laptop 2 weeks ago so this type of information is good to be reminded about. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell without your input data but your `std::cout` might need [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to increase the number of digits to print.